Passing Object1 as parameter to init of Object2 changes Object2 to also point at Object1
So, I have 3 classes: CreateMaze, MazeState, and MazeSolver.
Long story short, I pass a CreateMaze object as a parameter of MazeSolver. In the constructor method of MazeSolver, one of the attributes 'self.maze' is set equal to the CreateMaze object. In the method run_search() of the MazeSolver class, I create a variable 'start_state' that initializes a MazeState object and passes in self.maze (which contains the Maze() object). Now, in the contructor method of MazeState, there is also an attribute 'self.maze' that is set equal to the same Maze() object. However, as soon as this line of code runs while initializing the MazeState() object it turns from <maze_state.MazeState object at 0x000001BBDC88BD10> to  <maze.Maze object at 0x000001BBF2B60550>. So the MazeState object and its attribute 'self.maze' both equal the Maze() object. I'm so confused why this is happening. Help would be very appreciated :)
# main.py

# Load the maze file and initialize maze object
maze = Maze('maze2024.txt')

# Create a MazeSolver object and pass your maze object in
solver = MazeSolver(maze)

# Run the search algorithm
solver.run_search()

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, maze_file):
        self.maze_file = maze_file

        # Define Maze Structure
        self.SPACE = 0
        self.WALL = 1
        self.START = 5
        self.EXIT = 2
        self.VISITED = 3
        self.PATH = 4

        self.move_num = 0

        self.initial_maze = np.loadtxt(self.maze_file, dtype=np.int32)
        self.num_rows = self.initial_maze.shape[0]
        self.num_cols = self.initial_maze.shape[1]

class MazeSolver:
    def __init__(self, maze_obj):
        self.maze = maze_obj
        self.solution = None
        self.solution_path = None
        self.num_of_states_visited = 0


    def run_search(self, disabled_move=None):
        # Load starting Maze State onto frontier priority queue
        frontier = queue.PriorityQueue()
        start_state = MazeState(self.maze)  # Represents the starting configuration of the maze
...

class MazeState:
    def __init__(self, maze_obj, g=0, h=0, pred_state=None, pred_action=None):
        """ Initializes the state with information passed from the arguments """
        self.maze = maze_obj
        self.pos = self.maze.start  # Configuration of the state - current coordinates
        self.gcost = g  # Path cost
        self.hcost = h  # heuristic cost
        self.fcost = g + h  # cost-function value (gx + hx)
        self.pred = pred_state  # Predecesor/parent state
        self.action_from_pred = pred_action  # Action from predecesor/parent state to current state

I've tried changing a lot of the names (there are multiple 'maze''s). I tried creating the Maze object from within the MazeState class instead of passing it through as a parameter. I tried moving the attributes around, and in debugging it's always when the line runs giving the MazeState the Maze variable that it changes the object it's pointing to.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem.
